# Printing a complex matrix Fortran

Tags: matrix, printing, fortran, linear-algebra, complex-numbers

The complex matrix is declared this way:

```
complex(8) :: matrix(:,:)
```

How can I print this matrix with each element as: (a, b) or a+ib, and in a nxn format? (by that I mean as a square matrix, with a row per line, so there will be n rows and n columns)

This is the way I would print a real matrix with the format I want:

```
do i=1,n
    do j=1,n
        write(*, fmt="(f0.2, tr2)", advance="no") matrix(i,j)
end do
    write(*, fmt="(a)") " "
end do
```

But I'm not sure how to translate this to a complex matrix

Comment: Please ask one question per post.  Or at least keep one specific topic. The conjg() is completely unrelated to printing (and yes, it is elemental). What is the nxn format? Hav you tried anything?

Comment: @VladimirF Ok I took off the other question and explained what I meant by that format

Comment: What did you try? Please read "How to ask" and "Minimum Viable Example" under the Help section, then `edit` your question so we may efficiently help.

Comment: @SherylHohman Np, already made the changes you suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I print this matrix with each element as: (a, b)

Supposing you already know that `(a b)` is the default printing fotmat for `complex` type, Why isn't this just enough?

```
do j=1,n
  write(*, *) matrix(:,j)
end do
```

The output would be something like:

```
          (10.000000000000000,-20.000000000000000)              (10.000000000000000,-20.000000000000000)              (10.000000000000000,-20.000000000000000)
          (10.000000000000000, 20.000000000000000)              (10.000000000000000, 20.000000000000000)              (10.000000000000000, 20.000000000000000)
```

If you want something more customized, you could try something like this (adjusting the field width and precision):

```
do j=1,n
  write(*, "(*('('sf6.2xspf6.2x'i)':x))") matrix(:,j)
end do
```

That produces something like this:

```
( 10.00 -20.00 i) ( 10.00 -20.00 i) ( 10.00 -20.00 i)
( 10.00 +20.00 i) ( 10.00 +20.00 i) ( 10.00 +20.00 i)
```

Answer (score 2):

So far this is what has worked for me. Taking into account Clinton's advice:

```
character(19) fmt
fmt = '(F7.2,"+",F7.2,"i")'

do i=1,n
    do j=1,n
        fmt(8:8) = MERGE('+',' ',imag(a(i,j)).gt.0)
        write(*,fmt, advance="no") a(i,j)
    end do
    write(*, fmt="(a)") " "
end do
```

And the output is:

```
 -0.26   -0.00i  -0.00   -0.00i   0.00    0.00i   0.00    0.00i   0.00    0.00i   0.00    0.00i   0.00    0.00i   0.00    0.00i 
   0.00+   0.00i  -0.25    0.00i   0.00    0.00i   0.00    0.00i   0.00    0.00i   0.00    0.00i   0.00    0.00i   0.00    0.00i 
   0.00    0.00i   0.00    0.00i  -0.05    0.00i   0.00    0.00i   0.00    0.00i   0.00    0.00i   0.00    0.00i   0.00    0.00i 
   0.00    0.00i   0.00    0.00i   0.00    0.00i  -0.05    0.00i   0.00    0.00i   0.00    0.00i   0.00    0.00i   0.00    0.00i 
   0.00+   0.00i  -0.46   -0.00i  -0.00+   0.00i  -0.00+   0.00i  -0.50    0.00i   0.00   -0.00i   0.00    0.00i  -0.00    0.00i 
   0.32+   0.00i  -0.00+   0.00i   0.00   -0.00i  -0.00   -0.00i   0.00+   0.00i  -0.27    0.00i   0.00    0.00i   0.00    0.00i 
  -0.00+   0.00i   0.00   -0.00i  -0.00   -0.00i   0.24+   0.00i   0.00    0.00i   0.00    0.00i  -0.18    0.00i   0.00    0.00i 
   0.00    0.00i  -0.00   -0.00i   0.24+   0.00i   0.00   -0.00i   0.00    0.00i   0.00    0.00i   0.00    0.00i  -0.18    0.00i
```

If someone has a better suggestion I'll be glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that has worked in the past, it could be fine tuned quite a bit

```
  !! compile and link with  gfortran -I/usr/include -o PrintComplex  PrintComplex.f90 


Program PrintComplex

  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: N=16
  integer :: k
  real (kind=c_double) :: val(N)
  complex (kind=c_double_complex) :: in(N)
  character(19) fmt

  fmt = '(F7.2,"+",F7.2,"i")'
  val=(/(sin(3.14159d0*float(k)/3.d0),k=1,N)/)
  in=cmplx(val,-val/2)
  print *,"in"
  do k=1,N
     fmt(8:8) = MERGE('+',' ',imag(in(k)).gt.0)
     write(*,fmt)in(k)
  end do
End Program PrintComplex
```

The output is:

```
    in
   0.87   -0.43i
   0.87   -0.43i
   0.00   -0.00i
  -0.87+   0.43i
  -0.87+   0.43i
  -0.00+   0.00i
   0.87   -0.43i
   0.87   -0.43i
   0.00   -0.00i
  -0.87+   0.43i
  -0.87+   0.43i
  -0.00+   0.00i
   0.87   -0.43i
   0.87   -0.43i
   0.00   -0.00i
  -0.87+   0.43i
```